# Wrap wp print styles with <noscript>?

Tags: php, wordpress

As you know wp stylesheets in head are linked like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" id="my-id" href="my.css" type="text/css" media="all">
```

Is there any filter or function to wrap all css in head in a

`<noscript>` tag ?

Sory for question but did not find anything elsewhere ! Thanks in advance for helping me!

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the party but thought I would throw what I found. ( Assuming you are trying to achieve this because of Google Speed Insights and the block delivery of scripts https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/OptimizeCSSDelivery ).

```
add_action('wp_print_styles', 'my_print_styles');

function my_print_styles( $handles = false ) {
    global $wp_styles;
    if ( ! ( $wp_styles instanceof WP_Styles ) ) {
       if ( ! $handles ) {
        return array(); // No need to instantiate if nothing is there.
      }
    } 

echo '<noscript id="deferred-styles">';
wp_styles()->do_items( );
echo '</noscript><script>
  var loadDeferredStyles = function() {
    var addStylesNode = document.getElementById("deferred-styles");
    var replacement = document.createElement("div");
    replacement.innerHTML = addStylesNode.textContent;
    document.body.appendChild(replacement)
    addStylesNode.parentElement.removeChild(addStylesNode);
  };
  var raf = requestAnimationFrame || mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
      webkitRequestAnimationFrame || msRequestAnimationFrame;
  if (raf) raf(function() { window.setTimeout(loadDeferredStyles, 0); });
  else window.addEventListener(\'load\', loadDeferredStyles);
</script>'; }
```

Probably not the most elegant soultion to the problem but possibly will do the trick.